# Using WinDbg, is it possible to highlight the source line in MFC source code with WinDbg command?

Tags: debugging, memory-leaks, mfc, windbg

Background:

Occasionally, I get leaks in my MFC [dApp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decentralized_application) programs under development. MFC nicely dumps detected leak blocks out in the Output pane in Visual Studio showing their {block number} and hex address. Some leaks don't have source file paths and line numbers except to fx strcore.cpp etc. These leaks origins are hard-to-find and are in need of a better solution.

Studying up on WinDbg Preview with its Time Travel Debugging (TTD), I can see how this would be the right tool to quickly find the hard MFC leaks.

Leak Find Test:

I created a small MFC program and put a leak in it:

```
void LeakInThread()
{
  int* intLeak = new int[ 500 ];
}

wchar* leak = new wchar[ 100 ];
std::thread t1( LeakInThread ); // added leak in thread
t1.join();
```

The program produced: `{274698} normal block at 0x000001AFA34D9790, 200 bytes long.`

Using WinDbg I created a Trace file, Time Traveled to the end to make sure the leak was created, and used WinDbg commnd `!heap -i x000001AFA34D9790` to locate the TTD block where the error occurred. Here is the output:

`0:000> !heap -i 0x00000180F42E3790
Detailed information for block entry 00000180f42e3790
Assumed heap       : 0x0000000000000000 (Use !heap -i NewHeapHandle to change)
Header content     : 0xCDCDCDCD 0xCDCDCDCD
Block flags        : 0x1 LFH (busy )
Total block size   : 0x0 units (0x0 bytes)
Requested size     : 0xffffec00 bytes (unused 0x1400 bytes)
Subsegment         : 0x25dac2f1e46abc2eUser blocks not available`

Question: Is there a WinDbg command(s) that shows me the file and line number in the WinDbg source pane?

**Edit1:**

Experimented with this query command:

`dx -g @$MemRes = @$cursession.TTD.Resources.HeapMemory`

and got:

```
======================================================================================================================================
=           = ResourceId       = ResourceIdNew    = Size    = Function                   = ThreadId  = UniqueThreadId = Position     =
======================================================================================================================================
= [0x0]     - 0x180f4282870    - 0x0              - 0x4c    - ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap      - 0x59e4    - 0x2            - C819:58      =
= [0x1]     - 0x180f42b79d0    - 0x0              - 0x48    - ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap      - 0x59e4    - 0x2            - 5545:62      =
= [0x2]     - 0x180f4282870    - 0x0              - 0x0     - ntdll!RtlFreeHeap          - 0x59e4    - 0x2            - C827:13F     =
= [0x3]     - 0x180f42b32a0    - 0x0              - 0x6a    - ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap      - 0x59e4    - 0x2            - 2E1C:58      =
= [0x4]     - 0x180f744d330    - 0x0              - 0x24    - ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap      - 0x59e4    - 0x2            - 9609:4C      =
= [0x5]     - 0x180f74572e0    - 0x0              - 0x48    - ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap      - 0x59e4    - 0x2            - 960C:20D     =
= [0x6]     - 0x180f42b32a0    - 0x0              - 0x0     - ntdll!RtlFreeHeap          - 0x59e4    - 0x2            - 2E23:147     =
= [0x7]     - 0x180f42c1990    - 0x0              - 0x6a    - ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap      - 0x59e4    - 0x2            - FB23:58      =
= [0x8]     - 0x180f42d9fd0    - 0x0              - 0x0     - ntdll!RtlFreeHeap          - 0x59e4    - 0x2            - 12D1B:13F    =
= [0x9]     - 0x180f42c1990    - 0x0              - 0x0     - ntdll!RtlFreeHeap          - 0x59e4    - 0x2            - FB2A:147     =
= [0xa]     - 0x180f7453160    - 0x0              - 0x30    - ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap      - 0x59e4    - 0x2            - 9625:4C      =
= [0xb]     - 0x180f42c0810    - 0x0              - 0x6a    - ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap      - 0x59e4    - 0x2            - FB2E:58      =
= [0xc]     - 0x180f42b9160    - 0x0              - 0x0     - ntdll!RtlFreeHeap          - 0x59e4    - 0x2            - 2E25:4B      =
= [0xd]     - 0x180f42e9bd0    - 0x0              - 0x0     - ntdll!RtlFreeHeap          - 0x59e4    - 0x2            - 15481:13F    =
= [0xe]     - 0x180f42d9fd0    - 0x0              - 0x4c    - ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap      - 0x59e4    - 0x2            - 12D0D:58     =
= [...]
```

Since `ResourceID` looks similar to the MFC output address, I narrowed the output with this select query:

`dx -g @$MemRes.Where(x => x.ResourceId == 0x00000180F42E3790)`

but the output grid has no results.

**Edit2:**

"If the leak occurred in the MainFrame thread, the source file and line number are shown as well. No so when the leak occurred in another spawned thread." is not true. But leaks that don't point back to their source and line numbers do occur. There is still a possibility that the MFC debugger program is missing some source path defines allowing it to find the source code. More study is required.

**Edit3:**

On further review, the leaks produced from my MFC program, even with no keys pressed after launch, have different data addresses each time it is run. (The leaks were introduced many check-ins ago unnoticed until now). This means that I can't use WinDbg TTD's `dx ...` command to iterate through the trace's frames comparing data addresses to frame `LocalVariables` `Values` simply because the data addresses of the leaks will be different each time the program is run including when the Trace is being recorded. But, however, commands could be used to determine if a heap allocation is outstanding at the close of the program.

Comment: do you mean you have the address in assembly listing and want to find the source corresponding to that address ? if yes .open -a {your Address Here} should taske you to the source line  or use lsa . where . denotes the current rip/eip

Comment: I attempted `.open -a 0x180f42e3790` with no results. Looking in the LocalVariables in the Stack Frames I found `leak   0x180f42e3790 : "췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍???"   wchar_t *` so I know the address is a valid assembly listing value and is in the Trace.

Comment: you mean you are looking fir the source line cirresponding to the memory address returned by the new operator which behind the scenes used either heapalloc or virtualalloc?  you cant get it it is a dynamic address  there is no src line

Comment: if you need to track handles ,objects, debug heaps , pageheaps etc then you may have to look into gflags.exe options and enable flags to get stack traces of these

Comment: or share the bin where you are stuck deciphering as you say you made a sample

Comment: " are looking for the source line corresponding to the memory address returned by the new operator" Yes. Again, I can see that the address is there in the TTD trace's LocalVariables. Also, this is what the Debugger.chm documentation says: `This address must be contained in a known module. If the debugger can find the source file, the debugger loads and opens the file, and the line that corresponds to the specified address is highlighted.` I have made sure the the WinDbg settings for Source Paths and Symbol Paths (ie, pdb files) are set properly. It should work as you suggest.

Comment: Just now understood the second part of your suggested Answer. Ie, the part about being able to use ordinary unix-like commands like `ls` etc. Doing that I get `ls
No current source file`. That means it's a setup problem.

Comment: i meant if sometype foo = somevariantofAlloc(size) and the 181xxxx is foo then that 18xxx does not exist in source  windbg wont be able to find the source for that var  you need an address not some result of some operation is the 181xxx some result or an address?  ls is a windbg command list source not an unix cmd

Comment: I said unix-like. But I showed that the 181xxxx address does exist in the trace file. And here is more docu: `Source Path
The source path specifies the directories where the C and C++ source files are located.

If you are debugging a user-mode process on the computer where the executable file was built, and if the source files are still in their original location, the debugger can automatically locate the source files.

In most other situations, you have to set the source path or load the individual source files.`

Comment: The problem is the `address` I am using is the memory and not the instruction set address. I am going to have to iterate through the frames and local variables, and compare each one's local values to my given data address value to find out where it is.

Comment: Hi, does your program build in debug mode with full symbols?

Comment: Yes. WinDbg is fully functioning. So is the test program in Debug mode with symbols. The command line queries in WinDbg are working perfectly. I just need some assistance in finding the right set of WinDbg command line queries to be able to compare an MFC leak data address with the Time Travel Debugging trace values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Identifying the code that is leaking in a C++ application i use the commands provided in the below link.
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31382/Memory-Leak-Detection-Using-Windbg 
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

As Commented I am not sure what you are looking for these are few option that you can try

1) you can change the .asm options to make disassembly listing  show the line number and file name

like below

.asm

```
1:001> .asm
Assembly options: <default>
1:001> u .
vect!main [f:\src\vect\vect.cpp @ 9]:
00007ff6`e1d7efb0 4881ec98000000  sub     rsp,98h
00007ff6`e1d7efb7 48c7442460feffffff mov   qword ptr [rsp+60h],0FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEh
00007ff6`e1d7efc0 488d4c2448      lea     rcx,[rsp+48h]
00007ff6`e1d7efc5 e8576dffff      call    vect!ILT+19740(??0?
00007ff6`e1d7efca 90              nop
00007ff6`e1d7efcb c744242001000000 mov     dword ptr [rsp+20h],1
00007ff6`e1d7efd3 eb0a            jmp     vect!main+0x2f (00007ff6`e1d7efdf)
00007ff6`e1d7efd5 8b442420        mov     eax,dword ptr [rsp+20h]
1:001> .asm source_line
Assembly options: source_line
1:001> u .
vect!main [f:\src\vect\vect.cpp @ 9]:
    9 00007ff6`e1d7efb0 4881ec98000000  sub     rsp,98h
    9 00007ff6`e1d7efb7 48c7442460feffffff mov   qword ptr [rsp+60h],0FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEh
   10 00007ff6`e1d7efc0 488d4c2448      lea     rcx,[rsp+48h]
   10 00007ff6`e1d7efc5 e8576dffff      call    vect!ILT+19740(??0?
   10 00007ff6`e1d7efca 90              nop
   12 00007ff6`e1d7efcb c744242001000000 mov     dword ptr [rsp+20h],1
   12 00007ff6`e1d7efd3 eb0a            jmp     vect!main+0x2f (00007ff6`e1d7efdf)
   12 00007ff6`e1d7efd5 8b442420        mov     eax,dword ptr [rsp+20h]
```

or you can use .open -a address to open a new source window

for example

**.open -a .**

opens the source corresponding to the current Rip/Eip   . (dot ) denotes current Instruction Pointer

or you can use ls commands to

print the source lines  (use lsp to configure the pre and post line number counts default is 5 lines pre 5 lines post)

```
1:001> lsa .
     5: 
     6: using namespace std; 
     7: 
     8: int main() 
>    9: { 
    10:     vector<int> g1; 
    11: 
    12:     for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) 
    13:         g1.push_back(i); 
    14:
```

Comment: Both .asm and .open's Address parameter work if the Address in an instruction pointer. A memory leak address, derived from the dump in my MFC program, is a data address. Therefore, these WinDbg commands are not useful and therefore do not answer the question. Iterating through the heap allocations as I noted in my original posting, is still the only way I see that this problem can be solved.